# Неправильный путь файла в классе File

Tags: java

Есть файл, из которого я беру путь к директории, в файле каждый путь с новой строки

метод чтения

```
         public void read() {
                try {
                    reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileName));
                    while (reader.ready()) {
                        String s = reader.readLine();
                        list.add(s); 
                        }
                    reader.close();
                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
```

метод записи

```
 public void write(List<String>list) throws IOException{
    writer = new FileWriter(fileName);
     for(String s : list){
         File file = new File(s);
         writer.write(file.getAbsolutePath());
         writer.write(System.lineSeparator());
     }
     writer.close();
    }
```

main

```
public static void main(String[] args){
String pathtoread = "D:/ttt.txt";
 MyFileReader fileReader = new MyFileReader(pathtoread);
        fileReader.read();
MyFileWriter fileWriter = new MyFileWriter("D:/wwwe.txt");
 fileWriter.write(fileReader.getList());
}
```

проблема заключается в том, что каждый путь 1го файла при записи в файл, добавляет мою рабочую директорию, а потом только путь файла.

пример:

```
input:
D:/
D:/Games
D:/myFiles
output:
myworkdirectory\myProject\D:\
D:\Games
D:\myFiles
```

Почему так происходит?

Comment: есть вероятность того что вы когда подаете список с путями к файлам List<String>list то в нем уже содержатся неверные пути?

Comment: @KirillStoianov нету такой вероятности, я создаю обьект и в конструкторе инициализирую новый list

Comment: тогда еще один вопрос, если List<String>list - содержит в себе пути к файлам - зачем вы создаете эти файлы вместо того что бы сразу писать содерджимое List<String>list в файл?

Comment: @KirillStoianov у меня ещё после этого выполняется некоторая логика с этими файлами, потом мне надо записать путь к файлу и результат, но из-за не правильного пути сбивается логика

Comment: это странно, как вы генерируете пути к файлам или откуда их берете? когда вы начинаете писать в файл - вы уверены что этот файл не был создан ранее и в него ничего не записано?

Comment: перед тем как создать файл с путем который указан в List<String>list вы проверяете что там все правильно?